# Code first approach with mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I want to know if i'm doing things the good way. i have two models :

Personnel :

```
public class RH_Personnel
{
    public int RH_PersonnelID { get; set; }
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }
}
```

Attestation :

```
public class RH_Attestation
{
    public int RH_AttestationID { get; set; }
    public virtual RH_Personnel Employe { get; set; }
    public string TypeAttestation { get; set; }
}
```

i use migration to generate my tables. I know that i'm doing something wrong because when i add a new `Attestation` to Database it create a new `RH_Personnel` even if it already exist.

My controller :

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.TypeAttestation = new SelectList(db.RH_TypeAttestation.ToList(),"Type","Type");
        RH_Attestation Attestation = new RH_Attestation();
        Attestation.Employe = (RH_Personnel)HttpContext.Session["Employe"];
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Attestation/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(RH_Attestation rh_attestation)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //rh_attestation.Employe = (RH_Personnel)HttpContext.Session["Employe"];
            //rh_attestation.DateDemande = DateTime.Now;
            //rh_attestation.DateValidation = rh_attestation.DateDemande;
            //rh_attestation.Etat = ATTESTATION_ETAT_ENCOURS;
            db.RH_Attestation.Add(rh_attestation);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(rh_attestation);
    }
```

My view :

```
 @model Intra.Models.RH_Attestation

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Attestation", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div class="form_settings">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employe.Username)
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model => Model.Employe.RH_PersonnelID)
    <p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Nom") :
        </span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employe.Nom)
    </p>
<p>
        <span>
            @Html.Label("Prénom") :
        </span>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employe.Prenom)
    </p>
@Html.DropDownList("TypeAttestation", "Selectionner un type")
    <p style="padding-top: 15px;">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="submit" />
    </p>

</div>
}
```

Comment: What's happening is that you are creating a new `RH_Attestation` and setting its `Employe` property equal to a new `Employe`. What you want to do is check if the `Employe` exists, if it does, then call `.Attach(employe)`. What is the relationship that is intended between `RH_Personnel` and `RH_Attestation`?

Comment: The relationship is : single `RH_Attestation` is bind to a single `RH_Personnel` **one to one**

Comment: so that's exactly what's going on, you are creating an `RH_Personnel` first and then creating a new `RH_Attestation` and setting its `Employe` property equal to a new `RH_Personnel`. Depending on the workflow of your application and the create method for your `RH_Personnel` there is a different way to tackle this issue. Can you post the code you are using to create a new `RH_Personnel`?

Comment: The `.Attach(employe)` is the solution thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the Employee instance to the context before you do the SaveChanges().

Something like this should work;

```
RH_Personnel employee = (RH_Personnel)HttpContext.Session["Employe"];
db.RH_Personnel.Attach(employee);
rh_attestation.Employee = employee;
db.RH_Attestation.Add(rh_attestation);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I didn't test it so tell me if we are going in the right direction ;)

Comment: Thanks it work very well !! is this a good practice or just a work around?

Comment: :) Glad to help. I can't say it is a good practice, because i don't know. What I can tell is that it is not a workaround, because the context need to know about the object you are working with. Otherwise EF will consider the object a new one.